# For in statement

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am practicing the for-in statements.

I want to get all numbers bigger than five into a new array and print them to the console.

```
let numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

let result=[];

for (var number in numbers){
    result.push (number => number > 5)
    console.log(result);
}
```

Comment: Don't use `for...in...` for arrays. That's for iterating the properties of an object only.

Comment: what would I use then

Comment: `.push()` adds the parameter into the array it is called on. What do you expect to happen with `.push(number => number > 5)`? That whole construct should be a `.filter()` call only.

Comment: A regular `for` loop, `.forEach()`, `.filter()`, `.reduce()`, `while`, ... - what ever fits your needs (which would be `.filter()` in this case)

Comment: I know how to do it with filter ```const result = numbers.filter( number => number > 5 )
console.log(result)```

Comment: `let result = numbers.filter(number => number > 5)` might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Warning : `for( ... in ... )` gives you the _index_ of the elements. You won't be getting `1, 2, 3, 4` but `0, 1, 2, 3` (the index of the number 1 in your array is 0). If you want the elements themselves, use `for( ... of ...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is recommended not to use [for..in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) with arrays.

> The for...in statement iterates over all enumerable properties of an object that are keyed by strings (ignoring ones keyed by Symbols), including inherited enumerable properties. - MDN

You can use [for..of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) with Arrays. Since arrays are iterable objects.

```js
let numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

let result = [];

for (let num of numbers) {
  if (num > 5) result.push(num);
}

console.log(result);
```

Alternatively, you can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to get the numbers that is greater than 5

```js
let numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

let result = numbers.filter((num) => num > 5);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Does this really deserve an answer because there isn't already another question with the same topic here on SO?